# Why would one want to "end a playbook" if a variable is set?

Tags: ansible

I am reading some Ansible code that looks like this:

```yaml
---
- meta: end_play
  when: centos is defined

- name: Set centos variable
  set_fact:
    centos: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_distribution_version'][0:1] }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames: all
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  delegate_facts: true
  run_once: true
```

I have nobody to ask as the developer is long gone. Is this a common Ansible pattern?
If so, could someone explain why might this needs to be done? Are they trying to stop recursion or does it just look cool?

Comment: But could you bring a little but more of the context in with this snippet of YAML is used for a definitive answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful not to confuse *playbook* and *play*.
You can have multiple *plays* in a *playbook*.

Here is an example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - meta: end_play

    - debug:
        msg: I am not played

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: I am still played
```

That would still print the `debug` task of the second play, although not printing the one of the first, due to the `meta` task:

Actual output:

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [meta] **************************************************************

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: I am still played
```

---

So, yes, most probably, the snippet of YAML you are providing is there to ensure the variable `centos` is defined, and if it is already, skip the whole play to act on the variable in a further play.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - meta: end_play
      when: centos is defined

    - set_fact:
        centos: defined in play 1

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: centos
```

- The second play's `debug` would yield

  ```yaml
  ok: [localhost] => 
    centos: defined in play 1
  ```
- But, when you run the playbook with `--extra-vars "centos='from extra-vars'"`, it would, then, yield

  ```yaml
  ok: [localhost] => 
    centos: from extra-vars
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Let me comment on the second task

```yaml
- name: Set centos variable
  set_fact:
    centos: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_distribution_version'][0:1] }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames: all
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  delegate_facts: true
  run_once: true
```

This task runs once and iterates *set_fact* for all hosts. The loop

```yaml
with_inventory_hostnames: all
```

is equal to

```yaml
loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
```

Each iteration is delegated to a host and the [facts are delegated](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts) too. All these settings do exactly the same as the simple below task

```yaml
- name: Set centos variable
  set_fact:
    centos: "{{ ansible_distribution_version[0:1] }}"
```